# Cannot boot after failed Fedora Dual Boot installation with existing Windows 8

Tags: linux, windows, windows-8, fedora, mbr

I have a laptop that came with Windows 8 installed on one HDD with two partitions:

- C: (where Windows 8 is installed)
- D: (where my personal data is)

The OS was installed with a BIOS boot (MBR).
I wanted to install Fedora as a Dual Boot, so I downloaded Fedora Media Writer from the official website and let it download and create a bootable USB with Fedora 38 on it.

I shrank partition `D:` using `diskmgmt.msc` and unallocated ***70GB***.
When I started the Fedora installation software, under ***Installation Destination*** I selected the disk and ticked the ***automatic** option* under the ***Storage configuration***.
After that I began the installation and it started installing.
Midway in the installation it showed the following error:

```
The follow error occurred when install boot loader. The system will not be bootable. Would you like to ignore this and continue installation? Failed to set new efi boot target. This is most likely a kernel or firmware bug
```

I clicked **Cancel**(or abort, cannot remember how it was called, but it was **NOT** ***continue***)

After that the installer stopped and closed.
After I tried restarting the PC to check if everything is ok, during the booting phase it showed me the message:

```
Invalid partition table!
```

When I started the Fedora installation again using the `Advanced Custom(Blivet-GUI)` under **Installation Destination** -> **Storage configuration**, it showed Fedora Installation 64 with multiple partitions and Unknown with the old Windows partitions.
After deleting all the partitions (using the ***-***(minus) option), it removed all of them **except one** *EFI Partition* that had size of 600MB.
So at the end there were left 4 partitions:

- System reserves(from Windows)
- C: (from Windows)
- D: (from Windows)
- EFI Partition (I am guessing this is the BOOT partition that was created by Fedora and it changed the table from MBR to GPT)

I undid the changes and exited. Using a Windows 8.1 installation USB I tried Troubleshoot -> Refresh your PC option, but it failed with the following message:

```
The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again.
```

Using `diskpart` in Command Prompt from Advanced options, it listed the following partitions:

| Partition ### | Type | Size | Offset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Partition 1 | Primary | 350 MB | 1024KB |
| Partition 2 | Primary | 194 GB | 351 MB |
| Partition 3 | Primary | 200 GB | 195 GB |
| Partition 0 | Extended | 70 GB | 395 GB |
| Partition 4 * | Logical | 600 MB | 395 GB |
| Partition 5 ** | Logical | 1024 MB | 396 GB |
| Partition 6 | Logical | 68 GB | 397 GB |

*This is the BOOT partition that was created with the Fedora installation 
**I am guessing this is the SWAP partition

---

## My questions are:

1. **Can I make the Windows operational again ?**
2. **Is dual boot between Windows and Fedora possible if there are 2 partitions under Windows installation ?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: #1 Yes, but due to your unfortunate decision of an Legacy installation (any preinstalled Windows 8 is UEFI so if you later decided to reinstall it in "BIOS" mode that's exactly where your problems started) now you have to boot Windows (8) installation media and perform a boot repair. #2 The number of Windows partitions is immaterial for a dual-boot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The laptop (Dell Inspiron 5558) supports Legacy and UEFI, although since day one it was working under Legacy, and it was under Legacy that I tried to install Fedora (I double checked before install; It was also displayed in the boot from menu). No reinstall of Windows was done at any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some conclusions from your description :

- Since your data was not erased, the disk was hopefully
  not converted to GPT
- Since an EFI partition didn't exist before, most likely
  the Windows 8 installation was not EFI
- The Fedora installation was an EFI version and messed up your boot.
  Let's hope that it didn't also mess up the BIOS settings.

Let's try to fix the Windows locked problem using the
Windows installation USB and the two methods below.

**Run Automatic Repair**

- Boot from the Windows DVD/USB installation media
- Click "Repair your computer"
- Navigate to *Troubleshoot > Automatic Repair*
- Continue with the wizard to complete the process.
- Reboot.

If this didn't fix the Windows locked error, do this :

**Use bootrec to rebuild the BCD file**

- Boot from the Windows DVD/USB installation media
- Navigate to *Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt*
- Enter these commands :

  ```
  bootrec /FixMbr
  bootrec /FixBoot
  bootrec /ScanOs
  bootrec /RebuildBcd
  ```
- Remove the installation media
- Enter the `exit` command
- Reboot.

Comment: The first method worked, and I was able to boot windows. Thank you!
The 3 partitions created from the Fedora installation are still showing in Disk Management, including Partition 4 (G:) which indeed is EFI.
How should I delete the leftover partitions? Is via Disk Management ok? And why was Windows drive locked in the first place?

Comment: Or should the removal of the partitions be done from Gparted inside Linux?

Comment: For the small EFI partition, you might assign it a drive letter and see what's inside. If you intend to delete partitions, I advise taking an image backup of the disk with a product that has a restore boot media for emergencies. I like [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html) and [Create AOMEI Bootable CD/DVD/USB Based on Windows PE](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html). For testing Fedora, a virtual machine would be much less dangerous, easy to download from the internet.